# Two tables in Power BI, Is it possible to sync slicers without having a relationship?

Tags: database, powerbi, dax

So this one is a little strange. I am completely open to other suggestions of how to do this.

Table 1

[image]

This table is the full dataset. My goal is to create a bar chart that measures the frequency of each activity. The way I did this was by selecting "Enter Data" and adding a new table:

Table 2

[image]

This was entered manually, but essentially I made a list of all the activities from the Table 1. I then created a calculated column that filters Table 1 to only rows that include the specific activity, then returns a count of the rows. So in this example, row 1 is a and would return a count of 2.

My issue is now is trying to sync the slicers. A team lead should be able to come in and filter the data by Name to get their team metrics. I figured since the slicers would filter Table 1 down, then the calculated column in Table 2 would update the counts but it doesn't seem to work that way. I don't know of a way to create a relationship between the two either. If anyone has any ideas please share as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use bi-directional cross filtering, or a better solution is to write a measure that's used to filter the slicer visual.  That technique is covered here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/syncing-slicers-in-power-bi/